# Average numerical data but keep categorical data

Tags: r

I am looking to combine duplicate subjects, however some of my data is numerical and some is categorical.  The categorical values are duplicated but the numerical data may differ.  I want to average the numerical data but merge the categorical data.

For example:

```
Subject A   B
   1    L   1
   1    L   0
   2    R   1
   2    R   1
   3    L   0
   3    L   1
   4    R   1
   4    R   1
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
Subject A   B
   1    L   0.5
   2    R   1
   3    L   0.5
   4    R   1
```

I tried using aggregate() but it wasn't working since column A is non-numerical data.

Thoughts on how to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Subject, A) %>%
  summarize_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%
  data.frame()  # if you want a data frame
```

**yields:**

```
> df2
  Subject A   B
1       1 L 0.5
2       2 R 1.0
3       3 L 0.5
4       4 R 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  What if I had more columns (C, D, E) and those are categorical as well.  It seems like this method removed those columns.  I am working with a big data set, and this method removed about 50 columns of data, is there a way to keep those columns?

Comment: Just expand the `group_by()` to `group_by(Subject, A, C, E)`, that should work.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on the best way to group 50 columns together?

Comment: Please mark the question as answered when you're satisfied with the given answer (you can do this by clicking the check mark under the answer's vote counts). This stops people spending time on answering a question that has already been answered. For your new questions consider to ask a new one. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Subject A   B
   1    L   1
                 1    L   0
                 2    R   1
                 2    R   1
                 3    L   0
                 3    L   1
                 4    R   1
                 4    R   1", 
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, id := .N, by = c("Subject", "A")]
df[, avg := sum(B) / id, by = c("Subject", "A")]
df[, c("B", "id") := NULL]
df <- unique(df)
setnames(df, "avg", "B")

   Subject A   B
1:       1 L 0.5
2:       2 R 1.0
3:       3 L 0.5
4:       4 R 1.0
```